# Div fixa até certo ponto da página

Tags: jquery, html, css, rolamento

Estou desenvolvendo um website em que possui uma div fixa, mas que ao chegar a certo ponto, ela acompanha o scroll. Um exemplo é o site https://rockcontent.com/

Pelo que vi, é um script que a partir de certo ponto faz um cálculo da rolagem do scroll inversamente proporcional ao top da div.

Como faço isso?

Estou tentando com um script mais ou menos assim:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() <= $("#mudar").position().top) {
$('.cta').css({'position':'fixed'});
// $('.cta').css({'left':'75%'});
// $('.cta').css({'top':'50%'});
  }
  else {

 // $('.cta').css({'left':'75%'});
 // $('.cta').css({'top':'50%'});
//      x=0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").scroll(function() {
 x+=1;
  });
 });
  $('.cta').css({'top':'-(x)'});
}

 if ($(document).scrollTop() <= $("#ocultar").position().top) {
$('.cta').fadeOut();
  }
  else {
 $('.cta').fadeIn();
  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse é o caminho correto. O que falta mesmo é voltar a aplicar o posicionamento estático quando à distancia ao topo volta a ser pequena, para que fique posicionado normalmente. Isso seria aplicado no seu primeiro `else`.

Para o efeito de ficar fixo sem *fades*, como está no exemplo, nem precisa da maior parte do código que tem.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 210) { //ponto de mudança - 210 pixeis
    $('.cta').css({
      'position': 'fixed', //fixo a partir deste ponto
      'top': '100px',
      'right': '28px'
    });

  } else {
    $('.cta').css({ 'position': 'static' }); //se voltou a cima põe estatico
  }
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: #1bb7d0;
  padding: 40px;
}

#d2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 600px;
}

#cont {
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
}

.cta {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right:35px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus eu justo vel dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum tincidunt pharetra elit eget pretium. Aenean interdum, mauris eu efficitur feugiat, ex
  tortor tincidunt nisl, nec dictum metus odio vel urna. Integer volutpat elit ante, ac volutpat nulla hendrerit ac. In accumsan nisl eget elementum vulputate. Pellentesque volutpat molestie massa, nec facilisis elit rhoncus quis. Sed magna purus, viverra
  et scelerisque ut, malesuada dignissim ante. Pellentesque nulla quam, malesuada at eros ac, tincidunt aliquam eros. Quisque in nisl in ipsum cursus tempus. Sed sodales ligula quis eros hendrerit, id gravida nulla tristique. Duis molestie pellentesque
  risus euismod congue.
</div>
<div id="d2">
  <div id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus eu justo vel dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum tincidunt pharetra elit eget pretium. Aenean interdum, mauris eu efficitur feugiat,
    ex tortor tincidunt nisl, nec dictum metus odio vel urna. Integer volutpat elit ante, ac volutpat nulla hendrerit ac.</div>
  <div class="cta">Div com <br>texto fixo<br> que desce</div>
</div>
```

Optei por estilizar um pouco para ficar mais parecido ao exemplo que mencionou.

**Edit**:

Se precisa que também fique fixo em baixo, é necessário complicar um pouco mais pois a div tem de continuar a ser fixa mas ir variando a altura a partir do fim. Se deixasse de ser fixa voltava a parte do topo, onde ela foi colocada no html.

Exemplo:

```js
const alturaCta = $(".cta").height(); //capturar a altura do div fixo

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 210) { //ponto de mudança - 210 pixeis
    let novoTop = '100px'; //começa com 100px que é o normal
    
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1500){ //ponto de mudança do fim
      novoTop = (1500 + 100 - (alturaCta + $(document).scrollTop())) + "px";
      //                  ^----------- altura top que tem normalmente
    }
    
    $('.cta').css({
      'position': 'fixed', //fixo a partir deste ponto
      'top': novoTop, //agora novoTop
      'right': '28px'
    });

  } else {
    $('.cta').css({ 'position': 'static' }); //se voltou a cima põe estatico
  }
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: #1bb7d0;
  padding: 40px;
}

#d2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 600px;
}

#d3 {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  height: 1500px;
}

#cont {
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
}

.cta {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right:35px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus eu justo vel dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum tincidunt pharetra elit eget pretium. Aenean interdum, mauris eu efficitur feugiat, ex
  tortor tincidunt nisl, nec dictum metus odio vel urna. Integer volutpat elit ante, ac volutpat nulla hendrerit ac. In accumsan nisl eget elementum vulputate. Pellentesque volutpat molestie massa, nec facilisis elit rhoncus quis. Sed magna purus, viverra
  et scelerisque ut, malesuada dignissim ante. Pellentesque nulla quam, malesuada at eros ac, tincidunt aliquam eros. Quisque in nisl in ipsum cursus tempus. Sed sodales ligula quis eros hendrerit, id gravida nulla tristique. Duis molestie pellentesque
  risus euismod congue.
</div>
<div id="d2">
  <div id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus eu justo vel dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum tincidunt pharetra elit eget pretium. Aenean interdum, mauris eu efficitur feugiat,
    ex tortor tincidunt nisl, nec dictum metus odio vel urna. Integer volutpat elit ante, ac volutpat nulla hendrerit ac.</div>
  <div class="cta">Div com <br>texto fixo<br> que desce</div>
</div>
<div id="d3"></div>
```

Pode até melhorar o exemplo aplicando variáveis ou constantes em todos os valores que definem pontos de mudança. Eu não o fiz para que fosse mais claro para si.

Comment: mas eu preciso que ele fique fixo no final também, como no site mencionado acima

Comment: essa é minha dificuldade

Comment: @JoaoPedro Editei a resposta para contemplar esse cenário também